# Linux bridge_slave changes automatically to forwarding state

Tags: linux, bridge, iproute2

I'm trying to change the state of bridge slaves on Linux brigde system and It has very weird behaviour, changing all the time the port state to forwarding.

I.E:

Create a bridge with dummy interface as a slave (It occurs with other type of interace)

```sh
$ ip link add dev midummy type dummy
$ ip link add dev br type bridge
$ ip link set dev midummy master br
$ ip link set dev br up
$ ip link set dev midummy up
```

Check the status of the bridge slave:

```sh
$ brctl showstp br

...
midummy (1)
 port id        8001            state            forwarding
...
```

Try to change to blocking state

```sh
$ ip link set dev midummy type bridge_slave state 4
...
midummy (1)
 port id        8001            state            forwarding
...

$dmesg
[ 2414.108892] br: port 1(midummy) entered blocking state
[ 2414.108898] br: port 1(midummy) entered forwarding state
```

Why  kernel is changing bridge slave state to forwarding? 
Is there any bridge flag to configure this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the port is in forwarding state, that means is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this behaviour is due by stp and periodic bridge port status checking by timer even the stp is disabled completely. You can investigate the source code to find why this happens. I have found the workaround to execute your wish. Linux kernel supports an userspace stp daemon and you can write it or just link it to /dev/true to manage the stp states by hands.

Short demonstration:

```
# create the fake stp daemon and disable in-kernel stp handling.
# should return success exit code
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/bridge-stp

# start the fake stp daemon
brctl stp br on

# bring up the interface to the blocking state
ip link set dev midummy type bridge_slave state 4

# check the interface state again and again. state aren't changing
# except the transactions between disabled and blocking state, 
# that depends on bridge port status (UP or DOWN)
# use 'bridge monitor' to realtime monitoring of state changes

# !!! stop the fake stp before removing the symlink /bin/bridge-stp !!!
brctl stp br off

# and then remove the symbolic link to prevent future effects
rm /sbin/bridge-stp
```

Comment: I've tried it and the port doesn't change state to forwarding. I'm going to investigate it to know why kernel decides apply stp rules even with stp disabled in the bridge

Comment: If you know the C language, you can try to investigate the kernel source code. Very helpful site for this - https://elixir.bootlin.com/ . The function br_set_state are being called to change the bridge port state. You can start from checking the calls 'br_set_state(..., BR_STATE_FORWARDING)'. If you interested in learning of the linux network stack you can read these books: Understanding Linux Network Internals, Linux kernel networking: Theory and Implementation.

Comment: fwiw, this trick can't be used in a network namespace: [bridge: Only call /sbin/bridge-stp for the initial network namespace](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=ff62198553e43cdffa9d539f6165d3e83f8a42bc) since kernel 4.4 (and backports)